# Self-referencing association with copy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm looking for a proper way to make a specific self-referential association.

I have a Test model (users are taking part in classes and they try to pass tests). In case user does not pass the test I'd like to have a copy of this test and possibility to see in the original test all next attempts (copies) and in copies of original I'd like to see the id of the original test.

I already tried few things with self-referencing, however without luck.

**test.rb**

```
    has_many :retestizations
    has_many :retests, through: :retestizations
```

**retestization.rb**

```
    belongs_to :original, class_name: 'Test', foreign_key: 'original'
    belongs_to :copy, class_name: 'Test', foreign_key: 'copy'
```

**migration:**

```
    def change
        create_table :retestizations do |t|
          t.integer :original
          t.integer :copy

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: How is your `StudentTest` related over her. Write its association also.

Comment: sorry, it should be just a Test, not StudentTest...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use STI ?
Something like that ?

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Original < Test; end
class Copy < Test; end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html